# What are the "payoff" times for EvE learning skills?

Tags: eve-online

"Learning skills" are the skills that increase a character stat, thus reducing the time it takes to train other skills that require that stat.  This creates a trade-off.  I can learn skill X now, taking the "normal" amount of time to train it, *or* I can train the learning skill now, and then train skill X, which will now take slightly less time.

My question: what is the "payoff" time for each learning skill - how long do I have to spend training skills utilizing that boosted stat before the total training time is lower than it would be without the learning skill?

Ideally, I would like a chart that lists all the payoffs for all levels of all learning skills.

Comment: It appears [learning skills are no more.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/627051#627051)

Comment: Yeah, it's about time the got rid of those. Any game design that encourages training no useful skills when you first log on is a bad one. I just said hell with it, and trained them when I felt like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Learning skills were entirely removed from the game in mid-December 2010. Any points invested in learning skills were reimbursed. Players can instantly apply these points to any other skill they like.

Skill books are no longer available on the market, and any skill books sitting around in containers were reimbursed at the NPC selling price.

All new and existing characters have an extra 12 points in each attribute, to make up for the skills' removal.

The developers have [a more extensive post about the change over on the EVE Dev Blog](http://www.eveonline.com/devblog.asp?a=blog&bid=824).

Comment: It is important to note that the bonus SP gain for new characters were removed at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

<s>You probably don't really want to see a chart. It's a lot easier if you use [EVEMon](http://evemon.battleclinic.com/). It automatically looks at your queue and suggests learning skills that would make the training go faster than not learning them. If you keep using it, you'll automatically build up all the training skills you could ever need.</s>

Learning skills were removed. There is no pay-off for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yepp. Get EveMon. It'll do all those calculations for you...

Answer (score 1):

I found a fairly good overview on the EvE wiki, [here](http://www.eve-wiki.net/index.php?title=Skill#Learning_Skill_Payoff).  However, it is marked as potentially inaccurate due to changes that have been made in expansions/updates.

It also includes this provocative note:

"It is important to note that this is not a typical method and that a spreadsheet was used to calculate the absolute least amount of time. EVEMon does not give the best possible time either."

Comment: EVEMon uses information from the API. In my experience it has always been 100% accurate, and I have used it intensively for about half a year.

Comment: I would say EVEMon is *mostly* accurate - I have on rare occasions seen it show different numbers from the actual game. Also, due to recent API changes, you can only query the server once an hour, so if you change something in-game, it won't show up in EVEMon until the next update. Having said that - EVEMon is **awesome**.